# How do I get updated data to reflect when I input data to an html file that makes a php update query?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an html file that calls a DB table to pull up a record, and a php file that updates changes to the DB table, and directs the user back to the html file (to reload the updated record).

The html file loads the user data, takes the input, posts it to the php file, and php file writes it to DB table, and reloads the html file. However, upon reload, it shows the old record info and not the newly updated info. I look in DB table, and the update ran correctly and I see the new info. But it does not reflect on the page. How do I fix this?

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

---

HTML file:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'], " is logged in."; // echoes 1
}
else {
    echo "User not logged in";
}
?>

<?php

$query = "SELECT email, username, address1, city, state, postalcode, country
          FROM users
          WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    $_SESSION['userdata'] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
mysql_close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<body>
  <form name="userprofile" action="update.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Update User Profile</legend>
      <br class="clear" />
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['username']; ?>'/>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="address1">Address</label>
      <input type='text' name='address1' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['address1']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type='text' name='city' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['city']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type='text' name='state' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['state']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="postalcode">Postal code</label>
      <input type='text' name='postalcode' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['postalcode']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type='text' name='country' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['country']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />
      <br class="clear" />

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<br class="clear" />

</form>
</html>
```

---

PHP file:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'], " is logged in."; // echoes 1
}
else {
    echo "User not logged in";
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
$country = $_POST['country'];

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbtable';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'password'; //not really
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

$query = "UPDATE users
          SET   username ='$username',
                address1 = '$address1',
                city = '$city',
                state = '$state',
                postalcode = '$postalcode',
                country = '$country'
          WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]';";

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//echo $query;

mysql_query($query);
$retval = mysql_query($query);

if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close();

header('Location: update.html');

?>
```

Comment: Plus how do I get the update to show that it updated successfully. When I reload the html page, it seems to refresh the page and the update successful message seems to have been overwritten so I don't see it.

Comment: you can not see "Updated data successfully" because the page is redirected to update.html

Comment: AH makes sense... What is the best way to show that data was updated successfully and still be able to re-present the updated page with the updated data?

Answer (score 0):

you need to re assign updated data into your session once the data gets updated into the database table. you may need to modify your code like this

```
    <?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'], " is logged in."; // echoes 1
}
else {
    echo "User not logged in";
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$address1 = $_POST['address1'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
$country = $_POST['country'];

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'dbtable';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'password'; //not really
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

$query = "UPDATE users
          SET   username ='$username',
                address1 = '$address1',
                city = '$city',
                state = '$state',
                postalcode = '$postalcode',
                country = '$country'
          WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]';";

if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//echo $query;
$retval = mysql_query($query);

if($retval){
     $_SESSION['userdata']['username']=$username; 
     $_SESSION['userdata']['address1']=$address1; 
     $_SESSION['userdata']['city']=$city;
     $_SESSION['userdata']['state']=$state;
     $_SESSION['userdata']['postalcode']=$postalcode;
     $_SESSION['userdata']['country']=$country;
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    mysql_close();
    header('Location: update.html');
}else{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and this works too. Instead of reassigning all the variables, I just did a SQL select on the table right after the update in the php file. That seems to update all the session variables which are then passed back to the html file and is a little shorter to code too. THanks.

Comment: I am just wondering why when I used the header to call the html file from the php file, it did not repopulate the SESSION variables with the sql select statement. It worked when I repopulated the SESSION variables within the php file. Weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in index.html page. no need of index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'test';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = ''; //not really
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

$email='ripon';
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['email'], " is logged in."; // echoes 1
}
else {
    echo "User not logged in";
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    echo $address1; 
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'test';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = ''; //not really
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn);

    $query = "UPDATE user SET   password = '$address1' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[email]';";

    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    //echo $query;

    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    $retval = mysql_query($query);

    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    //mysql_close();
}


?>

<?php
$query = "SELECT  username, password, fullname FROM user WHERE username = '$_SESSION[email]';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    $_SESSION['userdata'] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
else
{
echo "error";
echo $query;
}
//mysql_close();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<body>
<?php var_dump($_SESSION['userdata']);?>
  <form name="userprofile" action="update.html" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Update User Profile</legend>
      <br class="clear" />
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type='text' name='username' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['username']; ?>'/>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="address1">Address</label>
      <input type='text' name='address1' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['password']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="city">City</label>
      <input type='text' name='city' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['city']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="state">State</label>
      <input type='text' name='state' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['state']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="postalcode">Postal code</label>
      <input type='text' name='postalcode' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['postalcode']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />

      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input type='text' name='country' value='<?php echo $_SESSION['userdata']['country']; ?>'/><br>
      <br class="clear" />
      <br class="clear" />

    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Update"  name="submit"/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
<br class="clear" />

</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Just not sure if I want to stick all the html & code onto 1 page.